# How can I change username or email or phone number information in LDAP?

Tags: php, arrays, ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I have this script through which I can change my LDAP password but I also want to change my username or full name or email or phone number. How can I do that? When I echo out the records I only get info like my name and email but what do I need to do to make ldap_modify change my full name or phone number or email or userid?

```
<?php
$server = "ldap://ldap";
$dn = "ou=People,DC=ssdfg,DC=sadad,DC=com";
$message = array();

function changePassword($server,$dn,$user,$oldPassword,$newPassword,$newPasswordCnf){
  global $message;

  error_reporting(0);

  $con=ldap_connect($server);
  ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

  $findWhat = array ("cn","mail");
  $findWhere = $dn;
  $findFilter = "(uid=$user)";

  #bind anon and find user by uid
  $sr = ldap_search($con,$dn,$findFilter,$findWhat);
  $records = ldap_get_entries($con, $sr);
   echo "<pre>";print_r($records);
  /* error if found more than one user */
  if ($records["count"] != "1") {
    $message[] = "Error E100 - Wrong user.";
    return false; 
  }else {
    $message[] = "Found user <b>".$records[0]["cn"][0]."</b>";
  }

  /* try to bind as that user */
  if (ldap_bind($con, $records[0]["dn"], $oldPassword) === false) {
    $message[] = "Error E104 - Current password is wrong.";
    return false;
  }
  else { }

  if ($newPassword != $newPasswordCnf ) {
    $message[] = "Error E101 - New passwords do not match! ";
    return false;
  }
  if (strlen($newPassword) < 8 ) {
    $message[] = "Error E102 - Your new password is too short! ";
    return false;
  }
  if (!preg_match("/[0-9]/",$newPassword)) {
    $message[] = "Error E103 - Your password must contain at least one digit. ";
    return false;
  }
  if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/",$newPassword)) {
    $message[] = "Error E103 - Your password must contain at least one letter. ";
    return false;
  }


  /* change the password finally */
  $entry = array();
  $entry["userPassword"] = "{SHA}" . base64_encode( pack( "H*", sha1( $newPassword ) ) );
  if (ldap_modify($con,$records[0]["dn"],$entry) === false){
    $message[] = "E200 - Your password cannot be change, please contact the administrator.";
  }
  else { 
    $message[] = " Your password has been changed. "; 
    //mail($records[0]["mail"][0],"Password change notice : ".$user,"Your password has just been changed."); 
    } 
}  

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes must be requested unless the ALL_ATTRIBUTES value is used, often this is an asterisk, but not always. The directory server must allow clients to retrieve values, and `userPassword` is often restricted to users with more privileges.

To modify attribute values, construct a modify request with the distinguished name, attribute, and the new values.

There are couple things of note:

- The LDAP client should check for response controls when the server transmits a response to a request. Failure to check for response controls will result in the LDAP client possibly missing important information from the server
- Why does this client base 64 encode the password? Directory server should never accept pre-encoded passwords (servers should be configured to reject pre-encoded passwords) because the server cannot execute password quality and history checks on pre-encoded passwords. For these and other reasons, transmitting pre-encoded passwords are a terrible idea, and all clients should reject this practice. LDAP clients must use a secure connection (SSL, TLS, or ipsec) and transmit passwords in the clear or use an external SASL bind request. For even better security use the [password modify extended request](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/11/12/ldap-password-modify-extended-request/) which requires the existing password, and can generate a password for the user.
- This client does not appear to be able to respond to an unsolicited notification from the server. Directory Servers may transmit an extended result that is unsolicited, that is, not in response to a client request. Clients must be able to handle these notifications which are often notifications that the server disconnected the client for whatever reason.

For more information, please see ["LDAP: Programming Practices"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/).

Comment: They are using SSL to connect to LDAP but my script is sitting on the same server/machine as LDAP so it doesn't need to do anything like SSL, TLS, or ipsec in order to change passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Change your $findwhat variable to have a * in it and you will get all of the user attributes that your account you are executing the search with can see.  Note that anonymous might not be able to see much and it certainly won't be able to update much.  My advice is to create an account in your directory that has all the privileges you will need and do all of your operations under that (except for authentication of course).

Modifying the other attributes should just be a matter of including them in your $entry array.  You need to use the proper attribute names but you'll see them when you print them out after changing $findwhat to a *.

Also Apache Directory Studio is a nice free tool for working with directories.  One thing cool about it is that you can view the search and modification logs and see the ldif operations it is sending to the directory.  Then you can replicate that in your code.